# Insert new row in sql table with same foreign key value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to be able to insert multiple rows in a table where one of the fields, a foreign key will be included in multiple rows.

Currently when I'm trying to do insert I'm getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object
>   'dbo.userGroupMembership' with unique index 'IX_userId'. The duplicate
>   key value is (264673).

Query I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO userGroupMembership(userId, usergroupId, created, adultAdminAccessLevel)
SELECT [userId], 12, GETDATE(), 0
  FROM [dbo].[userGroupMembership]
  where usergroupId = @UserGroupId
```

UserId is the foreign key field.

Any idea if I need to do any configuration change in the table or how can I be able to insert multiple rows with same foreign key?

Comment: Show the definition of the table.  You would appear to have an inappropriate `unique` constraint.

Comment: The foreign key is not the issue - there is also a unique key constraint on the table

Comment: Thx @Danny, do I need to set the 'Foreign Key Constraint' to No https://i.gyazo.com/42a947a87ccb7ae8374e153f6a0a4c78.png

Answer (score 1):

You have a unique index allowing one row per userID. If you truly want more than one row per userID just drop the unique index.

```
DROP INDEX dbo.userGroupMembership.IX_userID;
```

Comment: Thx @Anthony do I need to set this value 'Foreign Key Constraint' to No https://i.gyazo.com/42a947a87ccb7ae8374e153f6a0a4c78.png

Comment: That depends on what your intentions are. Foreign Keys don't have anything to do with uniqueness, they ensure that the value you are entering into that field exists in the table with the Primary Key that the Foreign Key references or is NULL. If you want to insert data with no reference in the parent table you could remove the Foreign Key, but that doesn't seem to be your concern

Comment: What are my options if I want to insert multiple entries in the usergroupmembership table for same userid? UserId is primary key in users table and foreign key in usergroupmembership table. Thx

Comment: Run my code, it removes the unique index preventing you from loading multiple entries with the same userid.

Comment: Thanks, will that mess anything else in the db regarding the existing relations users / usergroups or it will just remove the constraint?

Comment: It just removes the index. It will stop preventing multiple user IDs, but also since it is an index you lose that b-tree for possible query optimization. Unless you have an extremely large amount of users and groups that won't really be a concern for you.

Comment: @Laziale - As you said UserId is primary key in users table and foreign key in usergroupmembership table. In order to serve the Primary Key and Foreign Key relationship between Users table and usergroupmembership table, you no need to make the UserID value unique in usergroupmembership table. I suggest, you can drop the index as Anthony said.

Comment: If this solved your problem I would appreciate if you would mark as answered, thank you.